# CSS: How to widen the content area without increasing the popup size?

Tags: css

On my site.

If you click on one of the points on the map, you'll get a popup:
[image]

How do I widen the content area without affecting the size of the popup?

Whatever I do, only the size of the popup changes in this code:

```
.leaflet-popup-content {
    margin: 12px 18px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Add padding for `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper` with `padding: 12px 18px;` and remove the margin from `.leaflet-popup-content`

Comment: Define `content area`. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I can't wait to test all the answers out, I'm just at work right now and can't work on this at the moment, will update and select the best answer for my case. Will update around 5pm PT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove 18px for margin left, and right

```
.leaflet-popup-content {
    margin: 12px 0;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

And remove negative margins for the button

```
.event a.rsvp {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You will have this result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 261px;">
```

change this 261px to xxxpx
or

```
.leaflet-popup-content { width: xxxpx !important;}
```

Comment: <div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 261px;">

Answer (score 0):

for **.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper** you are not setting any width, and for **.leaflet-popup-content** you are explicitly setting the width of 261px.

So for this one-two solutions are there

**Solution 1**

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper{
   width: 313px;
   padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and remove the explicit width for **.leaflet-popup-content**, but the problem is when the content becomes more it will make issue

**Solution 2**

Add the padding as explicitly to the  **.leaflet-popup-content** so for this one once you add explicitly

```
.leaflet-popup-content{
  width: 261px; // explicit width
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I hope this will solve the issue